# WordPress / Gutenberg - Front and Editor Styles in One File?

Tags: css, wordpress, editor, wordpress-gutenberg

I've got a lot of custom stuff to style inside my current project ( first one made with Gutenberg) and editing two files (that include a lot of media queries) makes the task deeply infuriating.

Is it possible (and viable) to merge the 'frontend' styles and the editor styles within one CSS file in WordPress? So I can have the 'frontend' and 'editor' versions opposite one another in the CSS file and nothing flips out?

Comment: Are you creating a block, a theme, a plugin?

Answer (score 1):

This will cause unnecessary code in the admin panel.

Write CSS Separately for Gutenberg(editor styles). Gutenberg CSS file must include these: heading(h1,h2 etc...), , quote etc... Add this style even if the style element is for your front end. These attributes must be placed in editor styles.

Then enqueue the editor styles CSS file both.

Answer (score 0):

Ali is mostly right but the reasoning is kind of reversed.

You want the public views to be as small as possible, so while adding weight to Gutenberg would suck, adding weight to public views is much worse and will negatively impact page scores?